# Android - How to reuse SSL session for multiple HttpsUrlConnections

Tags: android, ssl, https

I'm trying to connect to a web server for my application that requires an SSL client certificate for authentication. From the standard documentation, I can't tell how to reuse an SSL session for multiple requests (I don't want to have to a full SSL handshake for every single request as this causes major overhead). Can someone point me in the right direction?

**EDIT**
I've seen in other posts that HttpClient might be a solution but as of Android 6.0 this has been deprecated in favor of HttpsUrlConnection. Using the following code:

```
SSLContext sslContext;
HttpsUrlConnection connection = url.openConnection();
connection.setSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
```

Does a new FULL SSL handshake occur (probably right?) everytime I create a new connection. How do I reuse the session?

Answer (score 0):

> I can't tell how to reuse an SSL session for multiple requests

It's automatic.

> (I don't want to have to a full SSL handshake for every single request as this causes major overhead)

It *would* cause major overhead, if it ever happened, but it doesn't.

> Does a new FULL SSL handshake occur (probably right?) everytime I create a new connection?

No.

> How do I reuse the session?

It should happen by default, subject to session timeouts at the server.